# How can I use Overleaf search/replace to add newlines?

Tags: overleaf, search

I have text in Overleaf (bibtex entries) with fields separated by comma and space `,` . I would like to replace these with comma, newline and 4 spaces (or tab). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

If you select regular replace search (as shown above) you can use `\n` in the replacement text to add newline

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me